# Can't insert links or images: "Permission denied to access property "apply""

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, images, javascript, jquery

For a few days now, I've been unable to insert images or links using the formatting toolbar above the post input textbox. When I press one of these two buttons,  I get:

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "apply"
```

and here is one more specific stack trace from the console:

```
jQuery 6
    r https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:2
    l https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:2
    b https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:2
    doLinkOrImage https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:2
    image https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:1
    f https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:1
    l https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:1
    onclick https://meta.stackexchange.com/Content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=e5b13c5c94ed:1
```

I use Firefox 77.0.1 on Devuan GNU/Linux Beowulf (~= Debian Buster without systemd). I have the Privacy Badger and uBlock Origin extensions installed - but the problem occurs also when I disable them for the site I'm trying to post something on. And - I've not had this problem before.

Note: I can of course insert links and images manually, i.e. spell out the markdown.

**Edit 2020-07-02 18:49 UTC+3:** I can no longer reproduce the issue. Pressing the link or the image buttons works again.

Comment: Is it possible to test or temporary whitelist SE sites from Privacy Badger and/or uBlock? I can't repro on Chrome.

Comment: @rene: 1. Yes. 2. It doesn't help, edited to indicate that.

Comment: Can you try with Chrome?

Comment: What happens if you use the shortcuts? `ctrl+g` and `ctrl+l`?

Comment: @DavidPostill: It works. But - I can no longer reproduce the problem at all, for some reason, now. Not sure why.